# Problem in Fourier expansion of Klein-Gordon field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, fourier-transform

I have $$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int d^4k\;e^{-ik\dot{}x}\tilde{\phi(k)}$$

Now, $\phi(x)$ satisfies the Klein-Gordon equation so we have $$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}(\partial_\mu\partial^\mu+m^2)\int d^4k\;e^{-ik\dot{}x}\tilde{\phi(k)}=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int d^4k(-k^2+m^2)\;e^{-ik\dot{}x}\tilde{\phi(k)}$$
So, unless $k^2=k_\mu k^\mu=(k^0)^2-\vec{k}\dot{}\vec{k}=m^2$ we have $\tilde{\phi(k)}=0$ so we can write $$\tilde{\phi(k)}=\delta(k^2-m^2)a(k)$$ and using this we have,$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int d^3k \frac{1}{2E_k}\left[e^{-iE_kx^0+i\vec{k}\dot{}\vec{x}}a(E_k,\vec{k})+e^{iE_kx^0+i\vec{k}\dot{}\vec{x}}a(-E_k,\vec{k})\right]$$

then it says **changing $\vec{k}$ to $\vec{-k}$ in the second terms leads to**

$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int d^3k \frac{1}{2E_k}\left[e^{-ik\dot{}x}a(k)+e^{ik\dot{}x}a(-k)\right]$$

I am having problem understanding this step, i.e the change where $\vec{k}$ is changed to $-\vec{k}$.

NOTES:
$A^\mu=(A^0,\vec{A})$ and $A_\mu=(A_0,-\vec{A})$

Comment: "*In mathematics, a change of variables is a basic technique used to simplify problems in which the original variables are replaced with functions of other variables.*" from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables)

Comment: Picture first defining a new variable $q=-k$ (if you're studying QFT you should know how to change variables!) and then renaming $q$ to $k$.